# FileReader FileNotFoundException when passing a self-built File

Tags: java, file, filenotfoundexception

This one's a fun one. I'd appreciate any bit of help, and no previous stackoverflow questions are pointing me in the right location. Docs also weren't very helpful to me.

I'm being thrown a FileNotFoundException with this block of code:

```
    public static int wordOccurance(Word t, File D) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int occurance = 0;

    BufferedReader mainReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(D));  
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(mainReader);
```

My tester file does not cause this to occur: ie.    "File tester = new File("C:\read.txt");"

But the problem occurs solely when I pass a File constructed by this method:

```
public static File makeAndCombineFile(String FileOne, String FileTwo) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader mainReader = null;// null holder value for the later useful bufferedReader
    Scanner kb = null;// null holder for later useful Scanner
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

OTHER CONDITIONS BETWEEN THESE TWO CHUNKS. MOST LIKELY NOT PERTINENT. ALSO RETURN FILE, JUST IF ONE INPUT IS NULL.

```
else //in case both are good to go and obviously not null
    {
        mainReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileOne));
        kb = new Scanner(mainReader);
        while(kb.hasNext())
            sb.append(kb.nextLine() + "\n");
        mainReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileTwo));
        kb = new Scanner(mainReader);
        while(kb.hasNext())
            sb.append(kb.nextLine()+ "\n");

        kb.close();
        return new File(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out what was going on here, but it looks to me like you think that this line:

```
return new File(sb.toString());
```

creates a file on disk containing the text read from the two scanners. *It does not.* It creates a `java.io.File`, which is basically a representation of a file path; the path represented by this `File` is the data read from the scanners. In other words, if FileOne and FileTwo contained the text to *War and Peace*, then the path represented by that file would be the the text of *War and Peace*. The file will not have been created on disk; no data will have been written to it. You've just created an object that refers to a file that does not exist.

Use a `FileWriter`, perhaps in conjunction with a `PrintWriter`, to save the lines of text into a file; then you can create a `File` object containing the name of that file and pass it to your other routine:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("somename.txt"));
while(kb.hasNext())
    pw.println(kb.nextLine());
pw.close();
return new File("somename.txt");
```

Comment: Ah yes, I understand your thought process. However, I understand I am not writing to the disk. If FileOne and FileTwo are both copies of War and Peace, I just want the object(File) representation of the the two mashed together. Essentially just creating a object File with War and Peace in it twice.

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean now!
Well, now that I'm on the right track I can't help but wonder why constructing a file from another file isn't allowed. It seems a little redundant though.